# IDE0057 Substring can be simplified

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I have the following lines of code:

```
string line = "<!--SomeValue=\"asdf\"-->";
int start = line.IndexOf("=\"") + 2;
return line.Substring(start, line.IndexOf("\"-->") - start);
```

This will return asdf.

I receive IDE0057 from the code analysis. I'm thinking there's a simple way to simplify :).

Edit:
The question is how do I simplify my code above to remove the IDE0057 message received. Reading the documentation provided for the message it is unclear how to fix it.

Comment: I guess the question is how to simplify? Visual Studio will provide a way to do that automatically in the lightbulb icon that shows up when you place the cursor in the offending line.

Comment: Rather than trying to parse XML by hand you should really just use an XML parser that's already been written to account for all of the complexities for you.

Comment: well  in one line `return line.Split("\"")[1]` - assuming that input string pattern doesn't change

Comment: Yeah... it's not properly formatted xml @servy, but thanks for marking me down :-/. It really doesn't matter the string, I'm trying to figure out exactly how this can be simplified to get rid of IDE0057 and I did some digging, but couldn't figure out the solution in my scenario.

Answer (score 10):

Gosh why didn't I know about the lightbulb. Thanks @Heretic Monkey.

```
string line = "<!--SomeValue=\"asdf\"-->";
int start = line.IndexOf("=\"") + 2;
return line[start..line.IndexOf("\"-->")];
```

In C# 8 string range operators were introduced. IDE0057 indicates that the substring method can be simplified by using the range operator instead. The above code uses the string range operator to grab from the desired start position, take the stuff in the middle up to the ending point desired. This removes the IDE0057 message.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges